# How to show/hide multiple divs using if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to display various divs conditionally, such that:

- display "x" div if it's not already
- display "y" div but only if "x" div is already being displayed
- display "z" div but only if "x" and "y" div are already being displayed.

With this code I can toggle a div to display and then not display:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

But then when I try do this for more than one div, it doesn’t work.

For example, this is what I tried:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else if (y.style.display === "none") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    console.log("It worked!");
  }
}
```

I made a couple CodePens showing those snippets:

- [This is the first snippet that works](https://codepen.io/RyanCodeDesign/pen/bGEpPra)
- [This is the second one that doesn't](https://codepen.io/RyanCodeDesign/pen/ZEQWdvw)

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to show both divs at the same time?

Comment: maybe you check against an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's walk through it in the first `myFunction`. That will work reliably because there's only two options - "is x set to `display: none`? if so, do X; otherwise, do Y" will always work as expected because it is simple binary logic (all the cases are handled, it basically just toggles the `style.display` property). As soon as you bring more complicated logic into the equation and take multiple factors into consideration, it gets a little more slippery, and you need to formulate your approach more carefully.

The logic you basically want is, if X is hidden, show it; if y is hidden AND x is visible, show it; finally, if X is visible AND y is visible AND z is hidden, show it.  You can write this in a really readable way by defining some quick `isHidden()`, `isVisible()`, and `show()` helper functions:

**EDIT**: FZs made a good point about classes not being caught by this logic. To account for that, all we need to do is add an "OR `classList` contains `hidden`" expression to the `isHidden()` check and voila.

```js
// helpers
let isHidden = (el) => el.style.display == "none" || el.classList.contains('hidden'),
    isVisible = (el) => !isHidden(el),
    show = (el) => el.style.display = "block";

// elements
let x = document.getElementById("div-x"),
    y = document.getElementById("div-y"),
    z = document.getElementById("div-z");

// click handler
let handleClick = () => {

  if (isHidden(x))
    show(x);

  else if (isHidden(y) && isVisible(x))
    show(y);

  else if (isHidden(z) && isVisible(y) && isVisible(x))
    show(z);

  else console.log("It worked!");
  
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<div id="div-x" style="display:none">X</div>
<div id="div-y" style="display:none">Y</div>
<div id="div-z" style="display:none">Z</div>

<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `elem.style` returns the *inline style* (`style="/* styles */"`) of `elem`.

As `#myDiv` and `#myDiv2` have only styles applied by stylesheets, `x.style.display` will return `undefined`, which isn't `"none"`.

To solve it, I recommend toggling a `.hidden` class on the elements:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");

  if (x.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    x.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else if (y.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    y.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    console.log("It worked!");
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="hidden"></div>
```

Or, to show them alternately (I assume that was the goal):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  x.classList.toggle("hidden")
  y.classList.toggle("hidden")
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv2" class="hidden"></div>
```